# How do I get a tkinter screen that isn't the root to disapere using either the destroy or withdraw fuction?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a log and quiz system using tkinter GUI. The gui screen allows for loging in and registering. This infomation is stored on an excel file saved as a csv.

The quiz portion is done on the python shell. What I want to do, is hide both the log in screen and main screen once the user has logged in and then if they choose the option of Logout, by entering 'D'. The main screen then comes back up.
I have been successful in getting rid of the main screen using the .withdraw function and can get it to appear back using, .deconify. But for some reason, I can't get rid of the log in screen.

It is possible that it's just in the wrong place, but I get an Attribute Error, which states 'function' object has no attribute 'withdraw'(I get the same for destroy)

Below is my code. It's not all of it. But the parts I think you'd need to be able to fix it.

```
def Destroy_menu():
    main_screen.withdraw()
    Login.withdraw()
def Quiz(quizfile, User):
    print(User, quizfile)
    global var
    NumberList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    Questions = True
    score = 0
    questions_answered = 0
    while Questions == True:
            try:
                    Number = random.choice(NumberList)
                    NumberList.remove(Number)
                    File = open(quizfile + ".csv", "r")
                    for line in File:
                            details = line.split(",")
                            ID_Number = int(details[0])
                            if ID_Number == Number:

                                    Question = (details[1])
                                    print("Question:",Question)

                                    Answer_one = (details[2])
                                    print("A):",Answer_one)

                                    Answer_Two = (details[3])
                                    print("B):",Answer_Two)

                                    Answer_Three = (details[4])
                                    print("C):",Answer_Three)

                                    Correct = (details[8])

                                    var = StringVar()
                                    X = input("Answer (e.g. A): ")
                                    print("\n")

                                    if X == Correct:
                                            print("Correct")
                                            score += 1
                                            print("Score:", score)
                                            questions_answered = questions_answered + 1

                                    else:
                                            print("Incorrect, answer was:",Correct)
                                            print("Score:", score)
                                            print("\n")
                                            questions_answered = questions_answered + 1
            except:
                    File.close()
                    print("Quiz Completed")
                    print("Final Score:", score, "/ 7")
                    input("Press enter to continue")
                    Questions = False
    #Writing to file
    file_writer = csv.writer(open(r"E:\NEA\Quiz\Scores.csv","a",newline =""))
    file_writer.writerow([User,quizfile,score,"NA"])

    Quiz_choice(User)
def Quiz_choice(User):
    Destroy_menu()
    flag = False
    print("\n" * 50)
    print("Pick a quiz")
    print("English Quiz (A)")
    print("Maths Quiz (B)")
    print("Science Quiz (C)")
    print("Logout(D)")
    while flag == False:
            opt = input(">>>: ")
            opt = opt.upper()
            if opt == "A":
                    quizfile = "English"
                    Quiz(quizfile,User)
                    flag = True
            elif opt == "B":
                    quizfile = "Maths"
                    Quiz(quizfile,User)
                    flag = True
            elif opt == "C":
                    quizfile = "Science"
                    Quiz(quizfile,User)
                    flag = True
            elif opt == "D":
                    print("Goodbye")
                    main_screen()
                    main_screen = Tk()
                    main_screen.deiconify()

            else:
                    print("Invalid input. Please input a letter")
def Login():
    global login_screen
    Login_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    Login_screen.title("Log in")
    Login_screen.geometry ("400x234")
    Label(Login_screen, text = "Please enter details below to login").pack()
    Label(Login_screen, text = "").pack()

    global Username_verify
    global Password_verify

    Username_verify = StringVar()
    Password_verify = StringVar()

    global Username_login_entry
    global Password_login_entry

    Label(Login_screen, text = "Username").pack()
    Username_login_entry = Entry(Login_screen, textvariable = Username_verify)
    Username_login_entry.pack()
    Label(Login_screen, text = "").pack()
    Label(Login_screen , text = "Password").pack()
    Password_login_entry = Entry(Login_screen, textvariable = Password_verify, show = '*')
    Password_login_entry.pack()
    Label(Login_screen, text ="").pack()
    Button(Login_screen, text = "Log in", width = 10, height = 20,command = Login_verify).pack()
```

Thanks in advance, and ask any questions you need to.

Comment: You seem to be using `main_screen` both as a function (or class?) and to hold a reference to a window. If it's a function, that explains the error you're getting. In other words, the question about how to use withdraw on a widget is to use withdraw on a _widget_, not a function.

Comment: You should call `login_screen.withdraw()` instead of `Login.withdraw()` inside `Destroy_menu()`.  Also, should all the `Login_screen` be `login_screen` instead inside `Login()`?

Comment: Acw 1668 : I have tried changing the function to be login_screen, but still get the same has no attribute error.

Comment: Bryan Oakley: I don't really understand what you are saying. Do I need to change it to just main instead of main_screen and is Main_screen = Tk, right or do I need to change that to something else?